# PHP MySQL - Can't echo a 'TEXT' value

Tags: php, mysql, text

I've created this thing to get a TEXT value from my database.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `ma_apps` WHERE `assignedto`='$_SESSION[username]'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$Appdata = mysql_fetch_array($result1) or die(mysql_error());
```

and then:

```
$app_content = $Appdata['1'];
echo $app_content;
```

but it echos and says nothing, although it's the right name of the key. And I already checked if I can get another value from the database from a key that is considered as "TINYINT", and it works well. But I fail to echo/get the "TEXT" keys from my database.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of the field? Does it start with `<?` by any chance?

Comment: > What is the value of the field? Does it start with <? by any chance?
@MichaelRushton

That!
Thank you very much, that is my fault. The value does start with "<". I removed this thing and now it works!

Comment: Cool. I've added it as an actual answer below.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to access to the second value in the array.
try this

```
$Appdata[1];
```

otherwise use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to create a array with the field name as key

Comment: I mean to access a field with the name of "1", but now I changed the field name to "ttt" - still can't echo the value.

Answer (score 1):

If your string resembles an HTML tag then it's going to be treated like an HTML tag and not show as a string on the screen. It's worth checking `view source` on your browser to see if your string starts with a `<`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `ma_apps` WHERE `assignedto`='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
```

Also,

```
$Appdata[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

try `echo $Appdata[0];` because you are asking for a column with name '1', vs asking for the index 1

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `ma_apps` WHERE `assignedto`='".$_SESSION[username]."'";
```

and

```
$app_content = $Appdata[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump($Appdata)` check the values inside the variable and use it properly. Index is without `'`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also just echo everything from the result set with:

```
<?php
    mysql_data_seek($result1,0);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        foreach ($row as $key => $value){
            echo $key." - ".$value;
        }
    }
?>
```

Then you will see the key value pairs